# <f:selectItems> JSF tag custom tooltip attribute

Tags: jsf, attributes, tags, title

Is it possible to add a "title" attribute to the  tag in JSF, for example:

```xhtml
<f:selectItems value="#{foo.fooList}" title="{foo.fooDescription}"/>
```

Generated HTML:

```xhtml
<select>
    <option value="foo1" title="description1">foo ex1</option>
    <option value="foo2" title="description2">foo ex2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have an elegant solution, but it can be done. I'm assuming JSF 2+ & Facelets VDL.

For a managed bean `Foo`:

```
@ManagedBean @RequestScoped
public class Foo {
  private List<SelectItem> fooList = Arrays.asList(
            new SelectItem("value1", "label1", "description1"),
            new SelectItem("value2", "label2", "description2"));

  public List<SelectItem> getFooList() {
    return fooList;
  }
}
```

You can use JavaScript to set the `title` attribute on the DOM node:

```xhtml
<h:selectOneMenu binding="#{requestScope.fooSelectOne}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{foo.fooList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<script>
(function() {
  var selectName = '#{requestScope.fooSelectOne.clientId}';
  var kids = document.getElementsByName(selectName)[0]
                     .getElementsByTagName("option");
  var index = 0;
  <ui:repeat value="#{foo.fooList}" var="_opt">
  kids[index++].title = '#{_opt.description}'; //TODO: escape this
  </ui:repeat>
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for `f:selectItems` tag there is no such (`title`) attribute available. You have this attribute in plain `option` tag in `HTML` but not in `jsf`. I think you should use plain `select` tag instead of `selectOneMenu` to get `title` value.

Comment: "You have this attribute in plain option tag in HTML" - its widespread adoption is quite a recent thing though, it is only supported from IE9 and up as far as I can tell. If there isn't one already, a feature request in the JSF jira on javaserverfaces.java.net is probably not a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your `<h:selectOneMenu` is as below.

```xhtml
<h:form id="myForm">
  <h:selectOneMenu id="myCombo">
    <f:selectItems value="#{foo.fooList}"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Now at `window.onload` you can iterate through `option`s and add the `title` as below

```xhtml
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
         var options = document.getElementById("myForm:myCombo").options;
         for(var i = 0; i &lt; options.length; i++) {
             options[i].title = "description" + i;
         }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

itemDescription attribute will not appear in seam 2.2.

Best solution would be using javascript to show tooltip for each select item.

```js
 <script type="text\javascript">
   function getTooltip(id){
     var options = document.getElementById(id).options;
         for(var i = 0; i &lt; options.length; i++) {
            options[i].title = "description" + i;
         }
    }
 </script>
```

if your  id is generated dynamically or other way, for eg.

```xhtml
 <rich:dataTable value="#{mybean.list}">
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{mybean.selectedValue}" onmouseover=getTooltip(this.id)>
     <f:selectitems value="#{mybean.selectlist}">
   </h:selectOneMenu>
 </rich:datatable>
```

This solution will work for all dynamically generated id's as well as simple

Answer (score 0):

To generate a `title` attribute on your generated `options`, you can simply use **passthrough** attributes like this:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{values}" p:title="Your title here"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use the variable defined via `<f:selectItems var="v" ...>` inside the passthrough-attribute :(. But BalusC show in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511351/how-to-add-tooltip-to-fselectitems#25512124) how to work around this limitation via `c:forEach`.