# How to add tooltip to f:selectItems

Tags: jsf, tooltip, selectonemenu

For example the `f:selectItems` component doesn't support the title attribute in some versions of JSF.

Would it be possible to replace JSF Components by their plain HTML counterparts using JSFC and do something like this?

```
   <select jsfc="h:selectOneMenu" value="#{cc.data}">
     <option jsfc="f:selectItems" value="${cc.listItems}" var="item" title="#{item.tooltip}"></option>
   </select>
```

instead of

```
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{cc.data}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{cc.listItems}" />
   </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Doing exactly so, replacing the latter by the above, I'm getting `"<f:converter> Parent not an instance of ValueHolder: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup"` Facelet TagExceptions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *Would it be possible to replace JSF Components by their plain HTML counterparts using JSFC and do something like this*

Nope. Ultimately, such a HTML element with `jsfc` attribute will be turned into a true JSF component in the JSF component tree and **only** the attributes supported by the component in question would be parsed and set as component attribute. The `title` attribute isn't among the supported attributes of [`UISelectItem`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiselectitem) component. I'm not sure what exactly you mean with "some versions of JSF". The standard JSF API already doesn't support it in first place. [JSF spec issue 529](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/faces-api/issues/529) describes this shortcoming and is currently still open.

If you're using JSF 2.2, make use of passthrough attributes. You only need to replace `<f:selectItems>` by `<c:forEach><f:selectItem>`, see also [Using f:selectItems var in passtrough attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671305/using-fselectitems-var-in-passtrough-attribute)

```
<... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<c:forEach value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{item}" a:title="#{item.tooltip}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Based on your question history you seem to be not using JSF 2.2 yet. If you can't upgrade, you basically need a custom renderer for `<h:selectOneMenu>`.
While creating the custom renderer, you could make use of the unused(!) `description` property of the `UISelectItem` class. I've answered this before on a similar question targeted at `<p:selectManyCheckbox>`: [Primefaces tooltip for p:selectManyCheckbox or other p:selectMany*/One*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780397/primefaces-tooltip-for-pselectmanycheckbox).

```
<f:selectItems ... var="item" itemDescription="#{item.tooltip}" />
```

Noted should be that creating the custom renderer for `<h:selectOneMenu>` is a pain, particularly if you intend to be JSF implementation independent. Theoretically, a custom `ResponseWriter` should be able to catch this, but unfortunately, the `<h:selectOneMenu>` only passes itself when writing `<option>`, instead of the `UISelectItem` in question.

Comment: Thanks. Very profound answer, indeed I did mean the attribute passthrough feature which isn't supported in anything < 2.2, the missing plain title attribute on components is a specification deficiency then as you say.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (JSF 2.2 / Mojarra 2.2.14), **itemDescription** worked out of the box. I.e:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item}" itemDescription="#{item.tooltip}" />
</c:forEach>
```