# Using f:selectOneRadio var in passtrough attribute

Tags: jsf, pass-through, selectoneradio, passthrough-elements

selectOneMenu with forEach as described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29676353/1521710)  does the job but when trying to use selectOneRadio in same case passthrough is ignored.

Is there any quick way to fix this.

```
 <h:selectOneRadio...>
  <c:forEach value="#{bean.countries}" var="country">
    <f:selectItem 
        itemValue="#{country}" 
        itemLabel="#{country.countryName}" 
        pt:data-icon="flag flag-#{country.isoCode}" />   
  </c:forEach>             
 </h:selectOneRadio>
```

It is not the same like in the given link 
selectOneMenu  - generates combo box
selectOneRadio - generates radio button goup
So it is using different renderes

Comment: Sorry, btw... I totally missed the link you already posted in the original question. Sorry, sorry

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7435039

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple

xhtml

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="a-radio" value="#{radioButtons.radioButtonJSF22}"/>
</f:metadata>

<label for="fooOption">
  <input type="radio" jsf:id="fooOption" pt:name="a-radio" pt:data-something="someValue" value="Wisconsin"/>
  <span>Wisconsin</span>
</label>
<label for="barOption">
  <input type="radio" jsf:id="barOption" pt:name="a-radio" pt:data-something="someValue"value="Minnesota"/>
  <span>Minnesota</span>
</label>
```

backing bean

```
@ManagedBean
public class RadioButtons {

private String radioButtonJSF22;


//...getter and setter for radioButtonJSF22
}
```

Thanks  to this site
http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/jsf-radio-buttons/