# Cannot access f:selectItems variable for passthrough attribute

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, passthrough-elements

I am using JSF 2.2 and I want to display a `title` attribute on each `option` element generated by `h:selectOneMenu` with **passthrough** by using an attribute of the `f:selectItems` variable.

It seems that I cannot access the `f:selectItems` variable to customize my **passthrough** attribute

Here is what I have done so far

My entity to display

```
public class ItemBean {
    private int id;
    private String strName;
    private String strDescription;

    public ItemBean(int id, String strName, String strDescription) {
        this.id = id;
        this.strName = strName;
        this.strDescription = strDescription;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

My backbean method to retrieve the list of entities

```
public List<ItemBean> getItems() {
    return new ArrayList<ItemBean>(){
        {
            add(new ItemBean(1, "Java", "Java programming language"));
            add(new ItemBean(2, "PHP", "Yet another language"));
            add(new ItemBean(3, "Python", "Not a snake at all"));
        }
    };
}
```

My `h:selectOneMenu` in the view

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}" var="item"
                           itemValue="#{item.id}"
                           itemLabel="#{item.strName}"
                           p:title="Description : #{item.strDescription}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The problem is that I cannot access the `item` variable for `p:title`, the output is just empty there.

Here is the code generated

```
<select>
    <option title="Description : " value="1">Java</option>
    <option title="Description : " value="2">PHP</option>
    <option title="Description : " value="3">Python</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to do it like that or is there another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem using `jstl` `c:forEach` loop and `f:selectItem` from this post [Using f:selectItems var in passtrough attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671305/using-fselectitems-var-in-passtrough-attribute)

Here is the code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{item.id}"
                      itemLabel="#{item.strName}"
                      p:title="Description : #{item.strDescription}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```