# how to add tooltip for selectItems tag in JSF

Tags: jsf, tooltip, selectonemenu

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="sType"value="#{sBean.sCriteria.sType}" style="width:200px;" styleClass="black" onchange="sTypeChanged();">
<f:selectItems value="#{sBean.allSTypes}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I am using the above code in my xhtml file.
I want to add "tool tip" in my selectOneMenu tag.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this question hope ot helps
[How to add tooltip to f:selectItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511351/how-to-add-tooltip-to-fselectitems)

Try ans use the title attributes best thing will be to bind the title in a map in the backing bean and use it here dynamically

Answer (score -1):

Use the title attribute of selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="sType"
                 title="tooltip_goes_here"
                 ...
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/selectOneMenu.html